# Typo3: Powermail extension Ajax Submit

Tags: typo3-9.x, powermail

In Which file we have to add the below code for submitting the form with ajax?

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.misc.ajaxSubmit = 1
```

Official documentation link: [Link](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/stable/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/AjaxSubmit/Index.html)

Answer (score 1):

it's not a good idea to add 'personal' typoscript to the original extension. With every update you will loose this change.

The better way is to build an own sitepackage, where you can add the typoscript.Here you find an easy way to build your own sitepackage:

https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/

And here is a [sitepackage tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/)

Comment: Hi, I have created a sitepackage. But I don't know where to write that code. can you please provide a path.

Comment: If you used the mentioned sitepackage builder the right place is: /Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript

Comment: Hi Robert, of cause you can add  'personal' typoscript. The snibbet Joy wants to add is a regular plugin setting. This normally has be be written in the setup.typoscript of your page. 

@joy-zalte: This setup.typoscript has to be located in the Template-modul on the rootpage. There are different concepts to deal with: from writing the setup on the root page directy, collecting a set of templates as setup in a sysfolder or include external template files.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the path where I need to add that code.

```
powermail/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.txt
```

Don't know it is right way or not but it's work.

Comment: this works now but like Robert mentioned, when the powermail extension will be updated(which will definitley happen), you will loose this change. The change should be made in your Sitepackage extension in the setup.typoscript file found in the path Robert mentioned in his answer.